# C++ shift values to begin of array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Need to move all values which is less than 1 in begin of array (WITHOUT SORT, and need solution without second array)

for example:

```
START ARRAY: {-2.12, -3, 7.36, 6.83, -1.82, 7.01}

FINISH ARRAY: {-2.12, -3, -1.82, 7.36, 6.83, 7.01}
```

There is my solution but it doesn't work very well, because at final we receive:

```
FINISH ARRAY: {-2.12, -3, -1.82, 6.83, 7.36, 7.01}
```

Values which less than 1, moves to begin of array, but 4 and 5 elements not in correct order

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double arr[6] = {-2.12, -3, 7.36, 6.83, -1.82, 7.01};

    cout << "Start array: " << endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        cout << arr[x] << ", ";
    }

    int index=0;
    double temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) { 
        if (arr[i] < 1) {
            temp=arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[index];
            arr[index] = temp;
            index++;
        }
     }
    cout << endl << "FINISH ARRAY: " << endl;
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        cout << arr[x] << ", ";
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If it's not just about the solution but about implementing this yourself, try to learn how to step through code with a debugger first. You can then tell at any point in time where things go wrong.

Comment: i know how to use debugger, but i use a dynamic arrays, and VS Code debugger not see the array values

Comment: I can't believe that. A pointer may be displayed as value per default, but you should be able to unfold it to display the elements behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition):

```
std::stable_partition(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), 
    [](double d) { return d < 1; });
```

---

If you want to implement it yourself, note, that in-place stable partition (using comparisons and swaps) cannot be done better than in `O(N log N)` time. Any algorithm with `O(N)` running time is incorrect.

One possible solution can be obtained with divide-and-conquer approach:

```
template<class It, class Pred>
It stable_partition(It first, It last, Pred pred) {
    // returns the iterator to the first element of the second group:
    // TTTTTFFFFFF
    //      ^ return value

    if (first == last)
        return last;
    if (last - first == 1) {
        if (pred(*first))     // T
            return last;      //  ^ last  
        else                  // F
            return first;     // ^ first
    }

    // Split in two halves
    const auto mid = first + (last - first) / 2;

    // Partition the left half
    const auto left = stable_partition(first, mid, pred);
    // TTTTTFFFFF
    //      ^ left
    //           ^ mid 

    // Partition the right half
    const auto right = stable_partition(mid, last, pred);
    // TTTTTFFFFF
    //      ^ right
    // ^ mid

    // Rotate the middle part: TTTTTFFFFFTTTTTFFFFF
    //                              ~~~~~~~~~~
    //                              ^ left    ^ right
    //                                   ^ mid
    const auto it =  std::rotate(left, mid, right);
    // TTTTTTTTTTFFFFFFFFFF
    //           ^ it
    return it;
}
```

It resembles quicksort, but here we do not actually sort the range. `std::rotate` itself can be easily implemented via three reverses.