# What is the difference between std::stable_partition() and std::partition()?

Tags: c++, algorithm, parameters, partition

```
stable_partition(vect.begin(), vect.end(), [](int x) { return x % 2 == 0; });

partition(vect.begin(), vect.end(), [](int x) {
  return x % 2 == 0;
});
```

Above code is to explain difference between two.

Comment: stable = Relative order of the elements is preserved

Answer (score 7):

"stable" means the order of equivalent elements won't change:

`std::stable_partition` from [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition):

> Reorders the elements in the range [first, last) in such a way that
>   all elements for which the predicate `p` returns `true` precede the
>   elements for which predicate `p` returns `false`. **Relative order of
>   the elements is preserved.**

Answer (score 7):

The best way to figure this out is probably with an example. Let me plagiarize the example from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{0, 0, 3, 0, 2, 4, 5, 0, 7};
    std::stable_partition(v.begin(), v.end(), [](int n){return n>0;});
    for (int n : v) {
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Running this one gets you: `3 2 4 5 7 0 0 0 0`. 3, 2, 4, 5, 7 are equivalent with respect to the relation defined by the `> 0` predicate and as expected they are not reordered.

However, if you replace `stable_partition` with `partition` for the same example you get: `7 5 3 4 2 0 0 0 0`. This time keeping the order of the equivalent elements was not guaranteed and obviously it wasn't.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in other answers, `std::stable_partition` preserves the relative order of elements in the groups for which the predicate returns `true` and `false`.

But this comes at a price: `std::stable_partition` has higher time/space complexity. If you can allocate additional storage, `std::stable_partition` can be implemented in `O(n)` time. However, in-place stable partition cannot be implemented in `O(n)` time. It can be done in `O(n log n)` time. An example of a simple divide-and-conquer algorithm can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59225308).

C++ reference for `std::stable_partition` [reads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition#Complexity):

> **Complexity (`std::stable_partition`)**
>
> Given `N = last - first`,
>
> Exactly `N` applications of the predicate and `O(N)` swaps if there is enough extra memory. If memory is insufficient, at most `N log N` swaps.

Also note that `std::stable_partition` [requires bidirectional iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59642958), whereas `std::partition` can operate on forward ones. However, on bidirectional iterators it is [more efficient](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition#Complexity):

> **Complexity (`std::partition`)**
>
> Given `N = std::distance(first,last)`,
>
> Exactly `N` applications of the predicate. At most `N/2` swaps if `ForwardIt` meets the requirements of `LegacyBidirectionalIterator`, and at most `N` swaps otherwise.

If relative order of elements after partitioning is not important, use `std::partition`.