# How to avoid swapping negative numbers when arranging for all negative and positive numbers in array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

This is the question I am looking at:

> Given an unsorted array Arr of N positive and negative numbers. Your task is to create an array of positive and negative numbers **without changing the relative order of positive and negative numbers**.

So, here's what my naive mind thought! I use a variation of insertion sort.

Here is the code:

```
void reorder(int arr[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int hole = i;
        while ((arr[hole] < 0) && (hole > 0)) {
            int temp = arr[hole];
            arr[hole] = arr[hole - 1];
            arr[hole - 1] = temp;
            hole--;
        } 
    }
}
```

This code changes the relative position of negative numbers, which is not desired. How can I avoid doing that in my code?

### Example

Input:

```
arr = { -12, 11, -13, -5, 6, -7, 5, -3, -6 };
```

Expected result:

```
-12 -13 -5 -7 -3 -6 11 6 5
```

But my result is:

```
-6 -3 -7 -5 -13 -12 11 6 5
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition).

Comment: Maybe better [std::stable_partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition), in order to keep the relative positions.

Comment: And if you want to implement `stable_partition` yourself for some reason, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59225308). Note that in-place stable partition cannot be implemented in `O(n)` time.

Comment: @Damien Even better, yes. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The problem with such homework questions is that there are often unstated and arbitrary constraints on what can be used. E.g. the absence of `std::vector` and `std::swap` suggests that the Standard Library can't be used. This would mean that the teacher is not competent to teach C++ .

Comment: Your while loop is moving the "current" negative number to the beginning of the array, which is too far. (Use smaller test cases, so you can trace through it either by hand or by printing intermediate results.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the assignment says *"Your task is to **create** an array"*... so if I understand correctly, you are not asked to *modify* the input array, but to create one.

So then the solution is quite trivial:

- Create an array of the same size as the input array
- Iterate the input array and copy negative values into the new array
- Iterate the input array again and now copy the positive values into the new array
- Return the new array.

This has linear time complexity.

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much. I was wondering if I was asking the right question. But it seems you read my mind

Comment: oh yes! I am sorry I was just trying to figure it out.

Comment: No problem. Thanks!